# Как программно запустить консоль и выполнять в ней команды

Tags: c#, cmd

Я работаю в Visual Studio 2015. В этом продукте есть компилятор для языка С/С++ cl.exe. Чтобы скомпилировать файл "нормально", то есть со всеми библиотеками, запускается командная строка разработчика (мне нужна именно командная строка, а не GUI интерфейс) - это все StartInfo. Далее указывается путь к компилятору и файлу с исходным кодом и параметрами в самой командной строке. Пути и параметры берутся из программы.

Как можно отправить команду для командной строки после ее запуска, если Process.Start и ProcessStartInfo уже задействованы?

Comment: Вот и перезадействуй.

Comment: @Qwertiy, перезадействовать нельзя. Нужно выполнить уже в запущенной консоли.

Comment: @rdorn вы имеете ввиду Process.StandartInput?

Comment: @csharper, сделай bat'ник и запускай его, раз надо в консоли.

Comment: @rdorn нужно откомпилировать исходный код.В моем случае с помощью cl.exe через командную строку разработчика(кср). Process.StartInfo используется для запуска кср с правами админа. Далее мне нужно ввести в строку путь к cl.exe с нужными параметрами для компиляции файла, которые задаются готовыми переменными в самой программе.

Comment: @Qwertiy так не пойдет

Comment: @rdorn в коде, в кср подгружаются нужные библиотеки для компиляции

Comment: @rdorn я работаю в визуал студио 2015 от майкрософт. В этом продукте есть компилятор для языка С/С++  называемый cl.exe. Чтобы скомпилировать файл "нормально", то есть со всеми библиотеками запускается командная строка разработчика(мне нужна именно командная строка, а не GUI интерфейс) - это все StartInfo. Далее указывается путь к компилятору и файлу с исх кодом и параметрами в самой кср. Пути и параметры берутся из самой проги.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой ответ можно найти в справке консоли

```
C:> cmd.exe /?
```

Стандартная консоль cmd позволяет объединять последовательные команды в одну строку, например так:

```
C:> ping localhost && ping localost
```

В результате ping будет вызван последовательно дважды.

Командная строка разработчика - это преднастроенная cmd. Настройка выполняется с помощью запуска bat-файла со специальным ключом `/k` для cmd.exe, чтобы после того как bat-файл отработает, окружение не было сброшено в дефолтные значения.

```
 %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
```

`%comspec%` это полное имя консоли, в большинстве случаев `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

исходя из выше описанного, достаточно к данной строке запуска дописать

```
&& cl.exe mycode.c <и прочие аргументы cl.exe>
```

Запуск из кода с помощью `Process.Start` будет выглядеть так:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = @"/k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"""//настраиваем консоль
              + @" && cl.exe mycode.c"//команда вызова компилятора
              + @" && exit",//закрываем консоль
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\",
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Особо замечу, что если компилятор завершит работу с ошибкой, цепочка команд будет прервана, команда `exit` не выполнится и консоль не будет закрыта

---

Альтернативное решение - перенаправить стандартный поток ввода и писать в него команды для выполнения, например так:

```
var compiler = @"cl.exe mycode.c"; //команда вызова компилятора
var exit = @"exit"; //закрываем консоль

var altStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = @"/k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""",
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

var process = Process.Start(altStartInfo);
using (StreamWriter sr = process.StandardInput)
{
    if (sr.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        sr.WriteLine(compiler);
        sr.WriteLine(exit);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("tttt");
}
```

Этот способ позволяет больше, в плане управления консолью, но если экзотические действия не требуются, то я бы предпочел первый способ.