# Как читать строку из запущенной консоли на C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Проблема заключается в следующем.

Я майнер, и во время майнинга периодически бывает перезапускается видеодрайвер(видеокарта gtx 1050ti). И после перезапуска у меня консоль майнинга продолжает работать, но при этом скорость падает до нуля. Решил я создать программу на c#.net по нажатию кнопки должен активироваться профиль системы на режим максимальной производительности и запуск майнера. При повторном нажатии на кнопку все становилось по умолчанию. Эта настройка производится при помощи батников.

Я решил что проблему можно обойти тем, что бы была возможность прочитывать последнюю строку консоли с определенной периодичностью что бы задать условие при котором моя программа бы перезапускала майнер.

По поводу решения проблем с видеодрайверами, прошерстил весь интернет, доводы были всякие: многие ссылались на заводской брак, кто-то давал советы по решению проблем(переустанови дравера, выключи разгон и т.д.), все это не помогает.

Проект я залил на GitHub - https://github.com/selt007/Run-Mine/tree/master/Run%20Mining/Run%20Mining

Заранее спасибо) Вот главная форма:

```
namespace Run_Mining
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public static bool action = false;
            public static string target_name = "miner";

            public Form1()
            {
                TopMost = true;
                InitializeComponent();
                timer.Interval = 15000;
            }

            private void power_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                action = !action;            
                if (action)
                {
                    Running.runBat();
                    power.Text = "Stop!";
                    power.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    timer.Start();

                    using (Running.process = new Process())
                  {
                     Running.process.StartInfo = Running.startInfo;
                     Running.process.Start();
                     Running.process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                     Running.process.WaitForExit();
                  }
                }
                else
                {
                    Running.killBat();
                    power.Text = "Start!";
                    power.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    timer.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Дополнительный класс:

```
class Running
    {
        public static ProcessStartInfo startInfo;

        public static void runBat()
        {
            try
            {
startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = @"/k ""D:\Майнинг\Zec Miner 0.3.4b\0.3.4b\fypool.bat""",
                    WorkingDirectory = @"D:\Майнинг\Zec Miner 0.3.4b\0.3.4b\",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                };
    var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            catch {
                MessageBox.Show("File fypool.bat not found! " +
                "The application must be in the same folder as the files!");
            }
        }
    }
```

А здесь я описал шаг таймера:

```
       private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var runningProcs = from proc in Process.GetProcesses(".") orderby proc.Id select proc;
        if (runningProcs.Count(p => p.ProcessName.Contains(target_name)) > 0)
        { }
        else
        { Running.runBat(); }

        using (StreamReader sr = Running.process.StandardOutput)
        {
            if (sr.BaseStream.CanRead)
            {
                sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы запускаете батники в консоли, и пытаетесь прочитать их вывод? А почему бы не запускать их, перенаправляя вывод своему приложению?

Comment: @VladD, все верно. Но я не совсем представляю как это сделать. Пробовал смотреть в интернете решения по этому вопросу, и не смог найти нужного мне. Не могли бы вы прислать пример кода, я думаю что ваш вариант, это то что нужно))

Comment: Вот тут есть пример: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VladD, это я находил в интернете, и это не совсем то что мне подходит. Дело в том что мне нужно запускать именно батник, т.к. при запуске cmd и аргумента в виде параметров для старта майнера у меня ничего не происходит. Перенаправление вывода в 'ProcessStartInfo' не работает, а 'Process' я не могу использовать из-за того что моя программа не работает должным образом.

Comment: А вы не пробовали `cmd /c остальные_параметры`? Должно по идее работать.

Comment: @VladD, пробую, но у меня ничего не получается. Если я правильно понимаю, то я должен задать аргумент в виде `cmd /c "путь до батника/fypool.bat"`. Извините за то что туплю, имею малый опыт в программировании..

Comment: Посмотрите еще тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723611/198316, там как раз про запуск батников с редиректом

Comment: @rdorn, я воспользовался вашей ссылкой, у меня не получилось решить проблему и я внес поправки в вопросе. Во время запуска у меня выводится исключение: `System.InvalidOperationExeption: "Поток StandardOut не был перенаправлен или процесс еще не был запущен"`. Запуск удался (побочный эффект - не отображается содержимое консоли из-за параметров `RedirectStandardInput` и `UseShellExecute`, при этом все работает). Не могу вывести содержимое консоли

Comment: Вам не нужен редирект на ввод, это нужно для построчного исполнения батника, вместо этого задайте RedirectStandardOutput = true. Потоки ввода и вывода редиректятся раздельно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316 тут есть пример с редиректом вывода. Можете из двух ответов собрать один.

Comment: @rdorn, я попытался сделать как указано в ответах на вопросы которые вы дали. У меня не получилось, я поправил код в шапке так как я сделал. Выводит исключение, то что я писал выше. Я не понимаю что у меня не получается, прошу помочь разобраться