# Программно открыть cmd.exe от имени администратора и перенаправить потоки ввода и вывода

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

Пишу небольшую утилиту, которая имеет необходимость раз в несколько секунд выполнять какую-либо команду командной строке Windows от имени администратора. Создавать для каждой команды новый процесс слишком тяжеловесно, а при попытке перенаправить потоки I/O получаю пустую строку. Можно ли как-то программно опрашивать командную строку от имени администратора, выполняя несколько запросов, не привязываясь к аргументам при создании процесса?

```
public CmdClient()
{
    _process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
                {
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                        FileName = "cmd.exe",
                        Arguments = "/c",
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
    };

    if (!_process.Start())
    {
        throw new Win32Exception("Process can't be started");
    }
}

public string Execute(string query)
{
    string result;
    using (StreamWriter sw = _process.StandardInput)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(query);
        using (StreamReader sr = _process.StandardOutput)
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd(); // пустая строка при любом запросе
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**UPD**: Такой подход работает, пока не попытаться запустить cmd на правах администратора (с параметром `/c`).

Comment: [ввод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723611/198316), [вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316). Особое внимание обратите на то, каким образом читаются данные из потока вывода при перенаправлении.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я видел эти ответы, и они не помогают решить мою проблему. Я обновлю формулировку вопроса.

Comment: У вас основная программа от имени пользователя вызывается?

Comment: `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />` установил

Answer (score -1):

Вы не правильно поняли смысл параметра `/C`. Вот что говорит по этому поводу `cmd /?`

> /C    Выполнение указанной команды (строки) с последующим завершением.

Как видите, параметр не имеет ни какого отношения к правам администратора для консоли. Более того, описанная вами "проблема" - это правильное поведение. Процесс `cmd` запускается, выполняет единственную команду, и завершается. Так как читаете выходной поток вы явно, а не по событию, то к моменту, когда дело доходит до чтения, процесс уже завершен и поток пуст. Если же читать по событию ([тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316)) то вы сможете зафиксировать вывод до завершения процесса консоли, но это не отменяет тот факт, что процесс будет завершен после выполнения единственной команды.

Для повышения прав используйте

```
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
```